i always get "No resource with given identifier found"
I am implementing a simple post query and I have implemented a similar one before and everything was fine, but here I get this error. And it occurs somewhere deep in the console that even I do not see it at once
controller
`class OperatorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $ldap_users = LdapUser::all();
        return view('pages.home')->with('ldap_users', $ldap_users);
    }

    public function storeUser(LdapUserStoreRequest $request)
    {
try {
            $validatedData = $request->validated();
            Log::error("тут "`your text` .$validatedData );

            $validatedData['full_name'] = $this->generateLogin($validatedData['full_name']);

            LdapUser::create($validatedData);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error("Ошибка при создании пользователя: " . $e->getMessage());
            return response("Ошибка при создании пользователя", 202);
        }
        return response('success', 201);
    }}`

web.php
Route::middleware("auth:web")->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [OperatorController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
    Route::post('/createUser', [OperatorController::class, 'storeUser'])->name('createUser');
});

js script
    <script>


        function createUser2() {
            var userPanel = document.getElementById("userPanel");
            var formData = new FormData(userPanel);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
            xhr.open('POST', '{{ route("createUser") }}');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 201) {
                    alert('Пользователь успешно создан!');
                    document.getElementById("createUserError").textContent = "";
                } else if (xhr.status === 202) {
                    document.getElementById("createUserError").textContent =
 "Ошибка: "  +xhr.responseText;
                } else if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("createUserError").textContent = "Ошибка введённых данных";
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
            console.error(xhr.statusText);

        }
    </script>

blade.php
<div id="createUserModal" class="modal">
    <div class="create-modal-content">
        <h2>Создание нового пользователя
            <button class="btn btn-danger close-button " onclick="closeCreateUserPanel()">Закрыть</button>
        </h2>
        <form id="userPanel">
            <div id="createUserError"></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile phone</th>
                    <th>Internal phone</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' name='full_name' id="createUserFullName" placeholder='Full Name'></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='m_phone' id="createUserMPhone" placeholder='Mobile phone'></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='i_phone' id="createUserIPhone" placeholder='Internal phone'></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='department' id="createUserDepartment" placeholder='Department'></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class='btn btn-primary  create-btn' type='button' onclick="createUser2()">Создать</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

always got code 200 and "No resource with given identifier found"
I tried rerouting
and changing the controller and trying to send the data differently, but all I see is this.

Probably you should use the browser's Network tool to debug this, if you haven't already - it's not clear what exactly you've looked at so far.

in chrome console i see this "No resource with given identifier found" and nothing else

I know. That's why I asked about what's happening in the Network tool relating to that request, instead of just the console

Also, do you get the same error if you test in a different browser (e.g. Firefox)? Sounds like a Chrome-specific error

Log::error("тут "your text` .$validatedData ); is a "typo" that happended here on SO I guess?

yeah mistake. In logs i just dont see anything. So this logs are useless because method wasnt called

You mean there is no HTTP request to your route shown in the browser's Network tool? Can you use the JS debugger and confirm if the xhr.open('POST'... line is executed or not?

the line is executed and the code moves on

If the line is executed then it must log something in the browser's Network tool relating to that resource. Also when you used it in the debugger, did you check and confirm that the URL it's attempting to open looks correct?

in chrome console network it writes
Request URL:
http://0.0.0.0:8080/createUser
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
302 Found
Remote Address:
0.0.0.0:8080
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

ok. So it returned a 302 (which is a redirect code), which isn't a case you're handling in the xhr.onload code you wrote.

But why it gives redirect code and doesn't even call the method from the controller. This is the first time I see redirection code and before I made a page with post requests too and it was not found there

Well the server is issuing a redirect, so presumably something in the server-side code and the routing engine is doing that. Maybe that route requires authentication, for example? Where is the 302 redirecting you to? It should contain a redirect target URL in the Location header of the response.

It redirects to the same page

this route need authentication and im authenticated

Does your authentication rely on session cookies? Is the cookie being transmitted in your request from the browser to the server?

it redirects to the same page...you mean the Location header also contains http://0.0.0.0:8080/createUser in the response??

No / I start at page http://0.0.0.0:8080/ than click and go to /createuser and it redirects me back to the http://0.0.0.0:8080/

mb smth goes wrong because i have
'''


            @auth
                {{ auth()->user()->email }}
            endauth
        

            auth('web')
                Выйти
                if(auth()->user()->role === 'admin')
                    Администрирование
                endif
             endauth
        

'''
in  begginingof the blade
That just creates some HTML in your page. It doesn't do anything to your XHR request

than click and go to /createuser...you mean your browser goes to /createUser as a new page, or are you just saying that the XHR request goes there? You're not describing this very clearly. I'm asking you specifically about the contents of the Location header in the response to the XHR request which genereated the 302. Can you confirm what that specific header field contains?

location http://0.0.0.0:8080/

I see. Thankyou. Well then, like I said, something in your routing engine is making it redirect back from that action. Next thing to check is the session cookie, as I mentioned earlier.

my authentication is based on tokens not on cookies as i understand

In that case you would need to send the auth token within the XHR request

My mistake i use sessions insted of tokens

In that case check the cookie is being sent correctly or not in the XHR request

as i understand cookie is ok

im stupid and just named parameters differently. In request rules i named mobile_phone but in html m_phone and didnt see mistakes from ide

We all make mistakes, glad you got it sorted it regardless! However, since this appears to be a simple typo issue, it's best to delete this question and answer to avoid unnecessary downvotes. Questions are typically closed when they're simple typo issues, which would prevent you from posting an unnecessary answer, but this one wasn't closed in time, and I see both have been downvoted already

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
